# Guice 4.0-beta5 doesn't work with Sitebricks 0.8.10

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, guice, guice-servlet, sitebricks

I just tried to deploy to GAE the sample HelloWorld app on Sitebricks website, using the latest versions of Guice and Sitebricks (4.0-beta5) and (0.8.10) and the injection fails. The is what the Google App Engine log shows:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Unable to get members for class com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder
  at com.google.sitebricks.SitebricksModule.configure(SitebricksModule.java:82) (via modules: com.myapp.servlet.MyGuiceServletConfig$1 -> com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder)

2) No implementation for java.util.Set<com.google.sitebricks.conversion.Converter> was bound.
  at com.google.sitebricks.SitebricksModule.configure(SitebricksModule.java:82) (via modules: com.myapp.servlet.MyGuiceServletConfig$1 -> com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder)

2 errors
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:448)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.myapp.servlet.MyGuiceServletConfig.getInjector(MyGuiceServletConfig.java:13)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:199)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:174)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-67803a1bdc416a76(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:218)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:385)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toProvider(BindingBuilder.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toProvider(BindingBuilder.java:100)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingBuilder.toProvider(BindingBuilder.java:43)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder$RealMultibinder.configure(Multibinder.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder.newSetBinder(Multibinder.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.multibindings.Multibinder.newSetBinder(Multibinder.java:124)
    at com.google.sitebricks.SitebricksModule.configure(SitebricksModule.java:82)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:253)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at com.myapp.servlet.MyGuiceServletConfig.getInjector(MyGuiceServletConfig.java:13)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/google/inject/internal/util/$ImmutableList;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2383)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ImmutableList
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-67803a1bdc416a76(Request.java)
    ... 35 more
```

It seems to me that the com.google.inject.util.internal package is completely missing from 4.0-beta5 and that's what's causing the ClassNotFoundException. Using 3.0 instead of 4.0-beta5 solves the problem.

Is it possible to somehow use the latest versions of both? Considering that both are "Google-born projects", I'm surprised that they are incompatible. Is there any better alternative to Sitebricks?

P.S. on a side note, sitebricks.org is down, even though there have been some recent (Jan 2015) commits... Is the project still actively maintained?

Answer (score 0):

The call to the missing class is coming from outside of the Guice package (specifically from an AppEngine package). Grepping both the latest code from Guice and Sitebricks shows that they do not attempt to reference this missing package anywhere (they both use Guava's ImmutableList).  What version of AppEngine are you using?